# Why does my reputation show +80 instead of +20?

Tags: bug, profile-page, reputation-history

When I visit the Reputation tab on my profile, I see +80 reputation in several places where the correct number should apparently be +20.

Here is a screenshot to illustrate this phenomenon in context. As far as I can discern, the surrounding reputation change numbers are correct.

[image: Screen shot with +80 rep on first answer]

I could supply additional screen shots, put perhaps better just to link to a few answers of mine which recently exhibited this issue.

- [Why does subprocess.Popen run in parallel but subprocess.run does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71883160/why-does-subprocess-popen-run-in-parallel-but-subprocess-run-does-not/71883260#71883260)
- [How to check string start with $ symbol and can have alphabet and positive digit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71837598/how-to-check-string-start-with-symbol-and-can-have-alphabet-and-positive-digit/71837635#71837635)

As of right now, these answers correctly display as +20 for me, but they did display as +80 around 30 minutes ago, and I have observed this a few times in the past, so I'm guessing this is a transient problem (and not, for example, a bug which was fixed while I was typing this!)

This is on Firefox Mobile on an iPhone 12 Mini.

Comment: [Here’s detailed data with examples](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377620/ghost-nonexistent-votes-in-reputation-tab). Yes, it’s a bug and it doesn’t seem to attract attention. An option is to use “post” instead of “time”.